# I need to sort this php array by time. AM PM format

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Vinyasa Yoga
                    [start_time] => 06:45 PM
                    [end_time] => 08:15 PM
                    [instructor] => Jock
                    [level] => All Levels
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Yoga FUNdamentals
                    [start_time] => 05:30 PM
                    [end_time] => 06:30 PM
                    [instructor] => Jock
                    [level] => Beginners
                )

        )

)
```

I need to sort this array by time, so the results are displayed earliest to latest.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

For example:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        array(
            "title" => "Vinyasa Yoga",
            "start_time" => "06:45 PM",
            "end_time" => "08:15 PM",
            "instructor" => "Jock",
            "level" => "All Levels"
        )
    ),
    array(
        array(
            "title" => "Yoga FUNdamentals",
            "start_time" => "05:30 PM",
            "end_time" => "06:30 PM",
            "instructor" => "Jock",
            "level" => "Beginners"
        )
    )
);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $aDateTime = new DateTime($a[0]["start_time"]);
    $bDateTime = new DateTime($b[0]["start_time"]);

    return $aDateTime > $bDateTime ? 1 : -1;
};

usort($array, "cmp");

print_r($array);
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Yoga FUNdamentals
                    [start_time] => 05:30 PM
                    [end_time] => 06:30 PM
                    [instructor] => Jock
                    [level] => Beginners
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Vinyasa Yoga
                    [start_time] => 06:45 PM
                    [end_time] => 08:15 PM
                    [instructor] => Jock
                    [level] => All Levels
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you. I searched for hours looking for this result, I was forgetting the [0] at the end of the $a & $b variables.